# Where dowload Ubuntu 20.4.1 ISO not-live

Tags: server, updates, repository, downloads, release-management

I wanto to install UUb-20.4.1_x64 on vmware but when I to downloaded ISO release, always is live-server, when I to created the repo in /etc/apt/source.list (echo "deb file:/mnt/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list), and I try to install packages, it shows unable to locate package SNMP, only is posible to do it with internet service? or where I can to download an ISO diff to live-server?... That have 3 partition? or I can to install with 2 partitions, 1- boot other to LVM?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I do not understand several parts of your question. The Ubuntu ISO image can be used to run Ubuntu from a USB thumb drive ("live") but it can also be used to install Ubuntu on a hard drive. You don't need a "non-live" ISO image. Regarding the SNMP package, did you run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: You pick the option for a direct install or a live session from the grub menu.